# Use regex in R to delete all characters in a string except specified words

Tags: r, regex

Using the R programming language, I want to be able to use the gsub function to remove all characters except two or three specified words.

I've tried a number of methods using look-behind, \\bMyWord\\b, and the caret symbol ^.

```
gsub("fbnmobile.*", "" , "fbnmobile akinremi temitope akinfemi gotvnspectran fbn akinremi temitope a and akinsanya arinola o ")
```

desired output:

"fbnmobile gotvnspectran fbn"

I want a template such that I can add or drop whole words that are to be excepted whenever I delete all of the other characters. In this case, I would specify to delete all characters except for words "fbnmobile", "gotvnspectran", and "fbn".

Also, I'll gladly accept a recommendation for a definitive guide on regular expressions for R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be easier to extract.  Specify the pattern of words to extract with OR (`|`) in `str_extract_all` from `stringr` and then `paste` the extracted words to a single string

```
library(stringr)
paste(str_extract_all(str1, "\\b(fbnmobile|gotvnspectran|fbn)\\b")[[1]], collapse=" ")
#[1] "fbnmobile gotvnspectran fbn"
```

---

Or using `gsub`

```
gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", trimws(gsub("\\b(fbnmobile|gotvnspectran|fbn)\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\\w+", "", str1, perl = TRUE)))
#[1] "fbnmobile gotvnspectran fbn"
```

#### daa

```
str1 <- "fbnmobile akinremi temitope akinfemi gotvnspectran fbn akinremi temitope a and akinsanya arinola o "
```

Comment: The gsub + trimws example seems more my speed. I tested it and I think it's my solution. I have thousands of financial transactions that I'm trying to clear out the personal names from so I can create a bag of words that isn't considering names of the app's users like so I can modify a string like "mobile transfer from thomas to mike" and only including words like "mobile transfer from to" before using it to train a model.